# How do I combine all of these scriptmanager scripts?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I ran YSlow on my page and it's complaining I have way too many scripts on my page. On inspection with Firebug I see most of them are of Validation and ScriptManager scripts:

[image]

How do I / Can I combine all of these scripts into one? Secondly when I downloaded the contents of WebForms.js it is not minified at all. This is it's content:

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
    this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
    this.eventArgument = eventArgument;
    this.validation = validation;
    this.validationGroup = validationGroup;
    this.actionUrl = actionUrl;
    this.trackFocus = trackFocus;
    this.clientSubmit = clientSubmit;
}
function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options) {
    var validationResult = true;
    if (options.validation) {
        if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            validationResult = Page_ClientValidate(options.validationGroup);
        }
    }
    if (validationResult) {
        if ((typeof(options.actionUrl) != "undefined") && (options.actionUrl != null) && (options.actionUrl.length > 0)) {
            theForm.action = options.actionUrl;
        }
        if (options.trackFocus) {
            var lastFocus = theForm.elements["__LASTFOCUS"];
            if ((typeof(lastFocus) != "undefined") && (lastFocus != null)) {
                if (typeof(document.activeElement) == "undefined") {
                    lastFocus.value = options.eventTarget;
                }
                else {
                    var active = document.activeElement;
                    if ((typeof(active) != "undefined") && (active != null)) {
                        if ((typeof(active.id) != "undefined") && (active.id != null) && (active.id.length > 0)) {
                            lastFocus.value = active.id;
                        }
                        else if (typeof(active.name) != "undefined") {
                            lastFocus.value = active.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (options.clientSubmit) {
        __doPostBack(options.eventTarget, options.eventArgument);
    }
}
var __pendingCallbacks = new Array();
var __synchronousCallBackIndex = -1;
function WebForm_DoCallback(eventTarget, eventArgument, eventCallback, context, errorCallback, useAsync) {
    var postData = __theFormPostData +
                "__CALLBACKID=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventTarget) +
                "&__CALLBACKPARAM=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(eventArgument);
    if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
        postData += "&__EVENTVALIDATION=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value);
    }
    var xmlRequest,e;
    try {
        xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e) {
        }
    }
    var setRequestHeaderMethodExists = true;
    try {
        setRequestHeaderMethodExists = (xmlRequest && xmlRequest.setRequestHeader);
    }
    catch(e) {}
    var callback = new Object();
    callback.eventCallback = eventCallback;
    callback.context = context;
    callback.errorCallback = errorCallback;
    callback.async = useAsync;
    var callbackIndex = WebForm_FillFirstAvailableSlot(__pendingCallbacks, callback);
    if (!useAsync) {
        if (__synchronousCallBackIndex != -1) {
            __pendingCallbacks[__synchronousCallBackIndex] = null;
        }
        __synchronousCallBackIndex = callbackIndex;
    }
    if (setRequestHeaderMethodExists) {
        xmlRequest.onreadystatechange = WebForm_CallbackComplete;
        callback.xmlRequest = xmlRequest;
        // e.g. http:
        var action = theForm.action || document.location.pathname, fragmentIndex = action.indexOf('#');
        if (fragmentIndex !== -1) {
            action = action.substr(0, fragmentIndex);
        }
        if (!__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            var queryIndex = action.indexOf('?');
            if (queryIndex !== -1) {
                var path = action.substr(0, queryIndex);
                if (path.indexOf("%") === -1) {
                    action = encodeURI(path) + action.substr(queryIndex);
                }
            }
            else if (action.indexOf("%") === -1) {
                action = encodeURI(action);
            }
        }
        xmlRequest.open("POST", action, true);
        xmlRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
        xmlRequest.send(postData);
        return;
    }
    callback.xmlRequest = new Object();
    var callbackFrameID = "__CALLBACKFRAME" + callbackIndex;
    var xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
    if (!xmlRequestFrame) {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");
        xmlRequestFrame.width = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.height = "1";
        xmlRequestFrame.frameBorder = "0";
        xmlRequestFrame.id = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.name = callbackFrameID;
        xmlRequestFrame.style.position = "absolute";
        xmlRequestFrame.style.top = "-100px"
        xmlRequestFrame.style.left = "-100px";
        try {
            if (callBackFrameUrl) {
                xmlRequestFrame.src = callBackFrameUrl;
            }
        }
        catch(e) {}
        document.body.appendChild(xmlRequestFrame);
    }
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        xmlRequestFrame = document.frames[callbackFrameID];
        if (xmlRequestFrame && xmlRequestFrame.document) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write("");
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.write('<html><body><form method="post"><input type="hidden" name="__CALLBACKLOADSCRIPT" value="t"></form></body></html>');
            xmlRequestFrame.document.close();
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].action = theForm.action;
            var count = __theFormPostCollection.length;
            var element;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                element = __theFormPostCollection[i];
                if (element) {
                    var fieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                    fieldElement.type = "hidden";
                    fieldElement.name = element.name;
                    fieldElement.value = element.value;
                    xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(fieldElement);
                }
            }
            var callbackIdFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIdFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIdFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKID";
            callbackIdFieldElement.value = eventTarget;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIdFieldElement);
            var callbackParamFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackParamFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackParamFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKPARAM";
            callbackParamFieldElement.value = eventArgument;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackParamFieldElement);
            if (theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"]) {
                var callbackValidationFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
                callbackValidationFieldElement.type = "hidden";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.name = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                callbackValidationFieldElement.value = theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"].value;
                xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackValidationFieldElement);
            }
            var callbackIndexFieldElement = xmlRequestFrame.document.createElement("INPUT");
            callbackIndexFieldElement.type = "hidden";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.name = "__CALLBACKINDEX";
            callbackIndexFieldElement.value = callbackIndex;
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].appendChild(callbackIndexFieldElement);
            xmlRequestFrame.document.forms[0].submit();
        }
    }, 10);
}
function WebForm_CallbackComplete() {
    for (var i = 0; i < __pendingCallbacks.length; i++) {
        callbackObject = __pendingCallbacks[i];
        if (callbackObject && callbackObject.xmlRequest && (callbackObject.xmlRequest.readyState == 4)) {
            if (!__pendingCallbacks[i].async) {
                __synchronousCallBackIndex = -1;
            }
            __pendingCallbacks[i] = null;
            var callbackFrameID = "__CALLBACKFRAME" + i;
            var xmlRequestFrame = document.getElementById(callbackFrameID);
            if (xmlRequestFrame) {
                xmlRequestFrame.parentNode.removeChild(xmlRequestFrame);
            }
            WebForm_ExecuteCallback(callbackObject);
        }
    }
}
function WebForm_ExecuteCallback(callbackObject) {
    var response = callbackObject.xmlRequest.responseText;
    if (response.charAt(0) == "s") {
        if ((typeof(callbackObject.eventCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.eventCallback != null)) {
            callbackObject.eventCallback(response.substring(1), callbackObject.context);
        }
    }
    else if (response.charAt(0) == "e") {
        if ((typeof(callbackObject.errorCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.errorCallback != null)) {
            callbackObject.errorCallback(response.substring(1), callbackObject.context);
        }
    }
    else {
        var separatorIndex = response.indexOf("|");
        if (separatorIndex != -1) {
            var validationFieldLength = parseInt(response.substring(0, separatorIndex));
            if (!isNaN(validationFieldLength)) {
                var validationField = response.substring(separatorIndex + 1, separatorIndex + validationFieldLength + 1);
                if (validationField != "") {
                    var validationFieldElement = theForm["__EVENTVALIDATION"];
                    if (!validationFieldElement) {
                        validationFieldElement = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        validationFieldElement.type = "hidden";
                        validationFieldElement.name = "__EVENTVALIDATION";
                        theForm.appendChild(validationFieldElement);
                    }
                    validationFieldElement.value = validationField;
                }
                if ((typeof(callbackObject.eventCallback) != "undefined") && (callbackObject.eventCallback != null)) {
                    callbackObject.eventCallback(response.substring(separatorIndex + validationFieldLength + 1), callbackObject.context);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
function WebForm_FillFirstAvailableSlot(array, element) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (!array[i]) break;
    }
    array[i] = element;
    return i;
}
var __nonMSDOMBrowser = (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf('explorer') == -1);
var __theFormPostData = "";
var __theFormPostCollection = new Array();
function WebForm_InitCallback() {
    var count = theForm.elements.length;
    var element;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        element = theForm.elements[i];
        var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tagName == "input") {
            var type = element.type;
            if ((type == "text" || type == "hidden" || type == "password" ||
                ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && element.checked)) &&
                (element.id != "__EVENTVALIDATION")) {
                WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
            }
        }
        else if (tagName == "select") {
            var selectCount = element.options.length;
            for (var j = 0; j < selectCount; j++) {
                var selectChild = element.options[j];
                if (selectChild.selected == true) {
                    WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (tagName == "textarea") {
            WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(element.name, element.value);
        }
    }
}
function WebForm_InitCallbackAddField(name, value) {
    var nameValue = new Object();
    nameValue.name = name;
    nameValue.value = value;
    __theFormPostCollection[__theFormPostCollection.length] = nameValue;
    __theFormPostData += WebForm_EncodeCallback(name) + "=" + WebForm_EncodeCallback(value) + "&";
}
function WebForm_EncodeCallback(parameter) {
    if (encodeURIComponent) {
        return encodeURIComponent(parameter);
    }
    else {
        return escape(parameter);
    }
}
var __disabledControlArray = new Array();
function WebForm_ReEnableControls() {
    if (typeof(__enabledControlArray) == 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    var disabledIndex = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < __enabledControlArray.length; i++) {
        var c;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            c = document.getElementById(__enabledControlArray[i]);
        }
        else {
            c = document.all[__enabledControlArray[i]];
        }
        if ((typeof(c) != "undefined") && (c != null) && (c.disabled == true)) {
            c.disabled = false;
            __disabledControlArray[disabledIndex++] = c;
        }
    }
    setTimeout("WebForm_ReDisableControls()", 0);
    return true;
}
function WebForm_ReDisableControls() {
    for (var i = 0; i < __disabledControlArray.length; i++) {
        __disabledControlArray[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
function WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, target) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var src = event.srcElement || event.target;
        if (src &&
            ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") &&
             (src.type.toLowerCase() == "submit" || src.type.toLowerCase() == "button")) ||
            ((src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") &&
             (src.href != null) && (src.href != "")) ||
            (src.tagName.toLowerCase() == "textarea")) {
            return true;
        }
        var defaultButton;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            defaultButton = document.getElementById(target);
        }
        else {
            defaultButton = document.all[target];
        }
        if (defaultButton && typeof(defaultButton.click) != "undefined") {
            defaultButton.click();
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function WebForm_GetScrollX() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        return window.pageXOffset;
    }
    else {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
        }
        else if (document.body) {
            return document.body.scrollLeft;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
function WebForm_GetScrollY() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        return window.pageYOffset;
    }
    else {
        if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
            return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        else if (document.body) {
            return document.body.scrollTop;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionSubmit() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value = window.pageYOffset;
        theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value = window.pageXOffset;
    }
    else {
        theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value = WebForm_GetScrollX();
        theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value = WebForm_GetScrollY();
    }
    if ((typeof(this.oldSubmit) != "undefined") && (this.oldSubmit != null)) {
        return this.oldSubmit();
    }
    return true;
}
function WebForm_SaveScrollPositionOnSubmit() {
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value = WebForm_GetScrollX();
    theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value = WebForm_GetScrollY();
    if ((typeof(this.oldOnSubmit) != "undefined") && (this.oldOnSubmit != null)) {
        return this.oldOnSubmit();
    }
    return true;
}
function WebForm_RestoreScrollPosition() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value, theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value);
    }
    else {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value, theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value);
    }
    if ((typeof(theForm.oldOnLoad) != "undefined") && (theForm.oldOnLoad != null)) {
        return theForm.oldOnLoad();
    }
    return true;
}
function WebForm_TextBoxKeyHandler(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var target;
        if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
            target = event.target;
        }
        else {
            target = event.srcElement;
        }
        if ((typeof(target) != "undefined") && (target != null)) {
            if (typeof(target.onchange) != "undefined") {
                target.onchange();
                event.cancelBubble = true;
                if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation();
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function WebForm_TrimString(value) {
    return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')
}
function WebForm_AppendToClassName(element, className) {
    var currentClassName = ' ' + WebForm_TrimString(element.className) + ' ';
    className = WebForm_TrimString(className);
    var index = currentClassName.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ');
    if (index === -1) {
        element.className = (element.className === '') ? className : element.className + ' ' + className;
    }
}
function WebForm_RemoveClassName(element, className) {
    var currentClassName = ' ' + WebForm_TrimString(element.className) + ' ';
    className = WebForm_TrimString(className);
    var index = currentClassName.indexOf(' ' + className + ' ');
    if (index >= 0) {
        element.className = WebForm_TrimString(currentClassName.substring(0, index) + ' ' +
            currentClassName.substring(index + className.length + 1, currentClassName.length));
    }
}
function WebForm_GetElementById(elementId) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        return document.getElementById(elementId);
    }
    else if (document.all) {
        return document.all[elementId];
    }
    else return null;
}
function WebForm_GetElementByTagName(element, tagName) {
    var elements = WebForm_GetElementsByTagName(element, tagName);
    if (elements && elements.length > 0) {
        return elements[0];
    }
    else return null;
}
function WebForm_GetElementsByTagName(element, tagName) {
    if (element && tagName) {
        if (element.getElementsByTagName) {
            return element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        }
        if (element.all && element.all.tags) {
            return element.all.tags(tagName);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
function WebForm_GetElementDir(element) {
    if (element) {
        if (element.dir) {
            return element.dir;
        }
        return WebForm_GetElementDir(element.parentNode);
    }
    return "ltr";
}
function WebForm_GetElementPosition(element) {
    var result = new Object();
    result.x = 0;
    result.y = 0;
    result.width = 0;
    result.height = 0;
    if (element.offsetParent) {
        result.x = element.offsetLeft;
        result.y = element.offsetTop;
        var parent = element.offsetParent;
        while (parent) {
            result.x += parent.offsetLeft;
            result.y += parent.offsetTop;
            var parentTagName = parent.tagName.toLowerCase();
            if (parentTagName != "table" &&
                parentTagName != "body" && 
                parentTagName != "html" && 
                parentTagName != "div" && 
                parent.clientTop && 
                parent.clientLeft) {
                result.x += parent.clientLeft;
                result.y += parent.clientTop;
            }
            parent = parent.offsetParent;
        }
    }
    else if (element.left && element.top) {
        result.x = element.left;
        result.y = element.top;
    }
    else {
        if (element.x) {
            result.x = element.x;
        }
        if (element.y) {
            result.y = element.y;
        }
    }
    if (element.offsetWidth && element.offsetHeight) {
        result.width = element.offsetWidth;
        result.height = element.offsetHeight;
    }
    else if (element.style && element.style.pixelWidth && element.style.pixelHeight) {
        result.width = element.style.pixelWidth;
        result.height = element.style.pixelHeight;
    }
    return result;
}
function WebForm_GetParentByTagName(element, tagName) {
    var parent = element.parentNode;
    var upperTagName = tagName.toUpperCase();
    while (parent && (parent.tagName.toUpperCase() != upperTagName)) {
        parent = parent.parentNode ? parent.parentNode : parent.parentElement;
    }
    return parent;
}
function WebForm_SetElementHeight(element, height) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.height = height + "px";
    }
}
function WebForm_SetElementWidth(element, width) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.width = width + "px";
    }
}
function WebForm_SetElementX(element, x) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.left = x + "px";
    }
}
function WebForm_SetElementY(element, y) {
    if (element && element.style) {
        element.style.top = y + "px";
    }
}
```

How do I do minification of this script?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this project](http://shinkansen.codeplex.com/) that uses a .NET port of YUI script and css compressor. We utilized something similar in one of the projects I worked on and it turned out great. Make sure to verify your JavaScript with JSLint or something similar before minimizing it as something very minor may screw things up (like missing a closing semicolon for example).

Comment: these scripts are generated on the fly and not there in my project. I hope I am clear. ScriptManager generates them at runtime from assembly. Secondly, for minification Chirpy is much better: http://chirpy.codeplex.com/ It includes Google closure compiler, YUI compressor, JsMin and other popular tools.

Comment: Ok, my mistake for not understanding the issue completely. As far as Chirpy is concerned - great tool, but I had some major issues with it on my local environment, which made it unusable.